# How to set null when reference table row is deleted, Ecto.Migration references/2

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have two tables `devices` and `devices_type`, I want to set null in `devices.type_id` when original row from `devices_types` is deleted.

```rb
#MyApp.Repo.Migrations.Devices
create table(:devices) do
    ...
    add :type_id, references(:device_type, on_delete: :nothing)
    ...
end
```

```rb
#MyApp.Repo.Migrations.DeviceType
create table(:device_type) do
    add :name, :string, comment: "Device type name"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference to documentation [references(table, opts \ [])](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#references/2), I use `on_delete: :nilify_all` option

```rb
#MyApp.Repo.Migrations.Devices
create table(:devices) do
    ...
    add :type_id, references(:device_type, on_delete: :nilify_all)
    ...
end
```

see too, check in options **on_delete**:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3

Comment: if someone wants to improve this answer, go on.